# Navigation Drawer how to move backend also to the right not just menu like in google gmail app

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Here is an example of `Navigation Drawer` which works superb. But I would like to have like in google gmail application that background is also moved to the right and not that navigation drawer gets over the background. How can i make this?

Comment: use that navigation drawer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: And read the design guidelines, which specifically call for the navigation drawer to overlay the content: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I think what he might be looking for is the [`SlidingPaneLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail App Uses the Navigation Drawer. But what you are looking for is SlidingPaneLayout. This should come in Handy - http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html